# How to get width in percentage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get value of the width in percentage using j-Query. 
I don't want to set value of in j-Query.I had tried width() method and css('width').They both return not return the result in percentage.

Html-Code

style.css

```
.demo{
width:50%;
}
```

jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var = $('.demo').css('width');//50px
var = $('.demo').width();//50
});
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: have to calculate it against the containing parent's width

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
  var parentWidth = $(document).width(); // parent element
  var demoWidth = ($(".demo").width()/parentWidth * 100).toFixed() +"%";
});
```

This would give you width in %

Comment: OP has not said that document is parent. You should replace $(document). If .demo is position:absolute you need $(".demo").offsetParent(), else $(".demo").parent().